# Is HTML case sensitive?

Tags: html

Is HTML case sensitive?

In an example I'm working with it says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Would `<!doctype html>` or `<!DocType Html>` work differently (or not at all)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, but it's considered good practice to keep HTML markup lowercase.

Comment: Incomplete. Tag names and attribute names are case-insensitive, while attribute values are case-sensitive.

Comment: That's because the names are part of the spec.  Values are whatever the user wants them to be.

Comment: @MattHughes, yes, but the attribute value case sensitivity is surely part of the spec, no?

Comment: Why is it good practice? References are missing.

Answer (score 25):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html

> In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, case-insensitively.
>
> Many strings in the HTML syntax (e.g. the names of elements and their attributes) are case-insensitive, but only for characters in the ranges U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z) and U+0061 to U+007A (LATIN SMALL LETTER A to LATIN SMALL LETTER Z). For convenience, in this section this is just referred to as "case-insensitive".

Comment: Nevertheless it is not a bad idea to write `DOCTYPE` upper-cased to be backward compatible to XML.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the other answers given, if you set the header `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml`, your browser will throw and XHML error if you don't type DOCTYPE in uppercase and html in lowercase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Using the XHTML content type isn’t recommended because the page won't be rendered in some browsers (e.g. IE8 and below), but it's certainly interesting to know.

Source: http://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell

Answer (score 9):

HTML is case insensitive. `XHTML`, that is being `XML` is [case sensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2).

Answer (score 7):

Generally, HTML is case-insensitive, but there are a few exceptions.  Entity names (the things that follow ampersands) are case-senstive, but many browsers will accept many of them entirely in uppercase or entirely in lowercase; a few must be cased in particular ways.  For example, Ç is &Ccedil; and ç is &ccedil;.  Other combinations of upper and lower case are no good.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use any case you want.