# upper case html tags encoded in lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am parsing an html file using lxml.html....The html file contains tags with small case letters and also large case letters. A part of my code is shown below:

```
        response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        html = response.read().decode('cp1251')
        content_html = etree.HTML(html_1)
        first_link_xpath =  content_html.xpath('//TR')
        print (first_link_xpath)
```

A small part of my HTML file is shown below:

```
<TR>
    <TR vAlign="top" align="left">
        <!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->
        <TD></TD>
    </TR>
 </TR>
```

So when i run my above code for the below html sample, it gives an empty list. Then i tried to run this line `first_link_xpath =  content_html_1.xpath('//tr/node()')` , all the upper case tags were represented as `\r\n\t\t\t\t'` in the output: What is the reason behind this issue??

NOte: If the question is not convincing please let me know for modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on unutbu's answer, I suggest you compare `lxml` XML and HTML parsers, especially how they represent documents by asking a representation of the tree back using `lxml.etree.tostring()`. You can see the different tags, tags case and hierarchy (which may be different than what a human would think ;)

```
$ python
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> doc = """<TR>
...     <TR vAlign="top" align="left">
...         <!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->
...         <TD></TD>
...     </TR>
...  </TR>"""
>>> xmldoc = lxml.etree.fromstring(doc)
>>> xmldoc
<Element TR at 0x1e79b90>
>>> htmldoc = lxml.etree.HTML(doc)
>>> htmldoc
<Element html at 0x1f0baa0>
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(xmldoc)
'<TR>\n    <TR vAlign="top" align="left">\n        <!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display(\'Metadata_WEB\', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide(\'Metadata_WEB\')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->\n        <TD/>\n    </TR>\n </TR>'
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(htmldoc)
'<html><body><tr/><tr valign="top" align="left"><!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display(\'Metadata_WEB\', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide(\'Metadata_WEB\')">Meta Data:</B></TD>--><td/>\n    </tr></body></html>'
>>>
```

You can see that with the HTML parser, it created enclosing `html` and `body` tags, and there is an empty `tr` node at the beginning, since in HTML a `tr` cannot directly follow a `tr` (the HTML fragment you provided is broken, either by a typo error, or the original document is also broken)

Then, again as suggested by unutbu, you can tryout the different XPath expressions:

```
>>> xmldoc.xpath('//tr')
[]
>>> xmldoc.xpath('//TR')
[<Element TR at 0x1e79b90>, <Element TR at 0x1f0baf0>]
>>> xmldoc.xpath('//TR/node()')
['\n    ', <Element TR at 0x1f0baf0>, '\n        ', <!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->, '\n        ', <Element TD at 0x1f0bb40>, '\n    ', '\n ']
>>> 
>>> htmldoc.xpath('//tr')
[<Element tr at 0x1f0bbe0>, <Element tr at 0x1f0bc30>]
>>> htmldoc.xpath('//TR')
[]
>>> htmldoc.xpath('//tr/node()')
[<!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->, <Element td at 0x1f0bbe0>, '\n    ']
>>>
```

An indeed, as unutbu stressed, for HTML, XPath expressions should use lower-case tags to select elements.

To me, '\r\n\t\t\t\t' output is not an error, it's simply the whitespace between the various `tr` and `td` tags. For text content, if you don't want this whitespace, you can use `lxml.etree.tostring(element, memthod="text", encoding=unicode).strip()`, where `element` comes from XPath for example. (this works for leading and trailing whitespace).
(Note that the `method` argument is important, by default, it will output the HTML representation as tested above)

```
>>> map(lambda element: lxml.etree.tostring(element, method="text", encoding=unicode), htmldoc.xpath('//tr'))
[u'', u'\n    ']
>>>
```

And you can verify that the text representation is all whitespace.

Comment: perfect..I solved it...strip() is the solution!! :) Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. I also thank you and @unutbu for using `lxml.etree.HTML()` and `lxml.etree.XML()` I had overlooked, and that are nice shortcuts to `lxml.etree.parse().getroot()`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML parser converters all tag names to lower case. This is why `xpath('//TR')` returns an empty list.

I'm not able to reproduce the second problem, where upper case tags get printed as `\r\n\t\t\t\t'`. Can you modify the code below to demonstrate the problem?

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''\
<TR>
    <TR vAlign="top" align="left">
        <!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->
        <TD></TD>
    </TR>
 </TR>'''

root = ET.HTML(content)
print(root.xpath('//TR'))
# []
print(root.xpath('//tr/node()'))
# [<!--<TD><B  onmouseover="tips.Display('Metadata_WEB', event)" onmouseout="tips.Hide('Metadata_WEB')">Meta Data:</B></TD>-->, <Element td at 0xb77463ec>, '\n    ']
print(root.xpath('//tr'))
# [<Element tr at 0xb77462fc>, <Element tr at 0xb77463ec>]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am sorry i believe that the error '\r\n\t\t\t\t' is because of the ampersand symbol in there. Could you please tell me how i could keep this uppercase tags as it is in lxml or is there any alternative library which can do this?

Comment: [HTML tags are case-insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4351857/190597), so I don't know of a way to preserve the case with an HTML parser. BeautifulSoup behaves the same as lxml in this respect. On the other hand, XML is case-sensitive, but in general you can not correctly parse HTML as though it were XML. Nevertheless, on the `content` posted above, if you change `ET.HTML` to `ET.fromstring`, then `root.xpath('//TR') works and the case of the tags is preserved.

Comment: Let me stress: It is better not to depend on the case of HTML tags, since, by its own specification, HTML tags are case-insensitive.

Comment: thanks @unutbu atleast now i know that lxml will convert everything to lowercase. I will try to implement this. Thanks for u r time