# Uncaught referenceerror ccifi is not defined test-partner:424 onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a javascript function.

Here my html code :

```
<li><INPUT TYPE="button"  VALUE="ccifi" onClick="ccifi()"></li>

<iframe SRC="" NAME="frame" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="300" ALIGN="right" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

**and here my javascript function :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function ccifi() {
    document.all.frame.src="http://www.ccfi.asso.fr/blog/";
  }

</script>
```

**And the error is :**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ccifi is not defined onclick
```

Comment: working for me, but why all of your attributes are in upper case. They should be in lower case.

Comment: @Mritunjay I think that was a common practice with HTML4. At the same time, it doesn't matter, because HTML4 and HTML5 is case insensitive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351857/is-html-case-sensitive - XHTML and XML are case sensitive

Comment: @Pete Doesn't matter where the function is defined - it's called `onclick`, which happens at any point after the page (the JavaScript) is loaded

Comment: here it is also working

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="button"  value="ccifi" onClick="ccifi();" />
```

should do it. you forgot the ";".

Greetz

Comment: It is certainly not the problem.

Comment: @nicael you forgot 'Greetz'.