# What is the difference between <P> and <p> in HTML?

Tags: html

So the thing is, I am currently analyzing html documents by reading them though java and I see that the p tag is one of the most commonly used tags. I know that it's there to provide a new line, but what I don't know is why in some documents I see

```
<P>Hello world!</P>
```

and in others

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

Sometimes both are even used in the same document.

It seems to have exactly the same effect but I am just wondering if there is any reason these two variations exist.

Comment: They are the same. It's depends on your taste ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags

Comment: HTML parsers are case insensitive; these are the same thing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351857/is-html-case-sensitive

Comment: p tag is not used for a new line. It is used to separate paragraphs.

Comment: @j08691: Well I googled it and didn't find anything. Anyway; thanks for the downvote :3

Comment: If you see both the uppercase and the lowercase versions in the same document, it only means one thing: sloppy coder(s).

Comment: One of them breaks your case-sensitive regexes, the other doesn't?  :-)

Comment: @afrazier: But which breaks them ;)

Comment: @Shomz: Thanks. That answer is bascially exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference.

In HTML, elements are case-insensitive.

However, in XHTML, you must use lowercase.

Comment: Thanks! I like the additional information you gave.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity

HTML is case-insensitive. as you can see in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Official documentation is definitely the best source there is on this topic.

Comment: The link seems to be down. This seems to be the new one: https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Answer (score 2):

`<p></p>` Is used for a new paragraph

HTML is case-insensitive, which means you can use both spellings.

Comment: Thanks! 
New line was the wrong term I guess. What I meant was paragraph, so thanks for clearing that.

Answer (score 1):

They're same. It does not matter if its lowercase or uppercase or even mixed.

Comment: Thanks! 
I was confused because some of the pages I read seemed to be automatically generated, which lead me to think there could be a difference.

Comment: Usually, HTML is very lenient. Pages can be generated even without <html> tags which is not a good way though ;) But that would be wrong in case you have to be verified by W3C (World Wide Web Consortium)

Comment: I think you can even do. <hTmL>, but what's the point. :D

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference. Inherited from SGML, HTML is not case sensitive for elements and attributes.

I prefere to use the lower-case form... Else I've the impression that the coder is shouting at me ^^