# rails: text_field attributes in lowercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following `text_field`:

```
<%= f.text_field( :with_created_at_gte, class: 'form-control datepicker filterrific-periodically-observed', 'data-provide': 'datepicker', "data-date-clearBtn": true ) %>
```

Which outputs:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker filterrific-periodically-observed" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-clearbtn="true" type="text" value="05/08/2015" name="filterrific[with_created_at_gte]" id="filterrific_with_created_at_gte">
```

The problem at hand is: my attribute is `data-date-clearBtn`, but Rails renders `data-date-clearbtn` (lowercase b). How can I avoid this problem? I also tried:

```
<%= f.text_field( :with_created_at_gte, class: 'form-control datepicker filterrific-periodically-observed', data: { 'provide': 'datepicker', "date-clearBtn": true } ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that html tags and attributes are case insensitive, check the comments in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351875/312907), so Rails is actually correct in this situation.

I don't think you can overwrite that behavior directly, you should either write your helper or type the html tag manually. The rails helper is designed in that way