# Correct Xpath for element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to scrape some data from [this page](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/services/wikify?source=At%20around%20the%20size%20of%20a%20domestic%20chicken,%20kiwi%20are%20by%20far%20the%20smallest%20living%20ratites%20and%20lay%20the%20largest%20egg%20in%20relation%20to%20their%20body%20size%20of%20any%20species%20of%20bird%20in%20the%20world).

I am using requests and lxml in python to do so.
Specifically I want the ids of the detected topics.

I wrote the following Xpath for them :

```
'//detectedTopic//@id'
```

This returned nothing.

Whereas the following worked without any issues:

```
'//@id'
```

The developer tools in Chrome showed that the first Xpath indeed points to the correct nodes.

What's wrong with it then?

Comment: can you try 2 examples below?
//detectedTopic/@id or 
//detectedTopic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `lxml.html` to parse the content, then the `HTMLParser` makes all the tags lowercase since [HTML is case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351857/190597):

```
import requests
url = 'http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/services/wikify?source=At%20around%20the%20size%20of%20a%20domestic%20chicken,%20kiwi%20are%20by%20far%20the%20smallest%20living%20ratites%20and%20lay%20the%20largest%20egg%20in%20relation%20to%20their%20body%20size%20of%20any%20species%20of%20bird%20in%20the%20world'
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.content

import lxml.html as LH
html_root = LH.fromstring(content)
print(LH.tostring(html_root))
```

yields

```
...
   <detectedtopics>
      <detectedtopic id="17362" title="Kiwi" weight="0.8601778098224363"></detectedtopic>
      <detectedtopic id="21780446" title="Species" weight="0.6213590253455182"></detectedtopic>
      <detectedtopic id="160220" title="Ratite" weight="0.5533763404831633"></detectedtopic>
      <detectedtopic id="37402" title="Chicken" weight="0.528161911497278"></detectedtopic>
   </detectedtopics>
```

but if you use `lxml.etree`  to parse the content as XML, then the case is not changed:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
xml_root = ET.fromstring(content)
print(ET.tostring(xml_root))
```

yields

```
...
   <detectedTopics>
      <detectedTopic id="17362" title="Kiwi" weight="0.8601778098224363"/>
      <detectedTopic id="21780446" title="Species" weight="0.6213590253455182"/>
      <detectedTopic id="160220" title="Ratite" weight="0.5533763404831633"/>
      <detectedTopic id="37402" title="Chicken" weight="0.528161911497278"/>
   </detectedTopics>
```

---

The content looks like XML not HTML, so you should use:

```
print(xml_root.xpath('//detectedTopic/@id'))
['17362', '21780446', '160220', '37402']
```

If content is parsed as HTML, then the XPath would need to be lowercased:

```
print(html_root.xpath('//detectedtopic/@id'))
['17362', '21780446', '160220', '37402']
```

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know the fact that `lxml.html` makes the tags lowercase as I am accustomed to use `lxml.etree` for xml parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ids by this:

```
'//detectedTopic/@id'
```

Also you can get the tag and extract your required attributes. Example:

```
for tag in tr.xpath('//detectedTopic'):
    print tag.attrib.get('id')
    print tag.attrib.get('title')
```