# Why does tagName method in JavaScript return HTML tags in capital letters?

Tags: javascript, tagname

Why does tagName method in JavaScript return HTML tags in capital letters?
HTML tags should be written in small letters.

Comment: why html tags should be written in small letters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351857/is-html-case-sensitive

Comment: *"HTML tags should be written in small letters."* Why do you think that? (It's what **I** do, but...)

Comment: @IłyaBursov the answer on that question is a bit of a non-answer unfortunately.

Comment: Because it's [canonical](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-104682815): `The HTML DOM returns the tagName of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The older versions of **HTML** back when **JavaScript** was first created used all caps for tag names by convention instead of today's lowercase. To stay backward-compatible with older code `tagName()` still returns all uppercase and has been stuck that way.

Comment: This was actually my assumption as well because I seemed to remember that uppercase was considered proper markup back in the day. ( in fact I went so far as to look up the old space jam site from the 90s to check it out, and I did see some examples of it ). Still, I don't believe it was ever mandatory for html markup to be uppercase, just "good practice"( as fickle as that is lol). As far as maintaining it for backwards compatibility, I guess I doubt that's a conversation, since there really isn't a whole lot of reason to change it, right?

Answer (score 5):

Because that's [how `tagName` is defined](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-tagname):

> The tagName attribute’s getter must return the [context object](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#context-object)’s [HTML-uppercased qualified name](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element-html-uppercased-qualified-name).

HTML tag names (and attribute names) are not case sensitive, but the canonical version of the tag name is in all caps, regardless of how the HTML that created the element was written:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(div) {
  console.log(div.tagName);
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<DIV></DIV>
<Div></Div>
```

This is quite handy, since it means code looking at `tagName` doesn't have to worry about doing a case-insensitive comparison if it needs to know whether the tag matches a specific tag name. That is, `if (element.tagName === "DIV")` is reliable in HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

To be complete, note that [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName):

> Returns the tag name of the element on which it's called. For example, if the element is an , its tagName property is "IMG" (for HTML documents; it may be cased differently for XML/XHTML documents).

See result below with svg:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].forEach(function(el){
  console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

```html
 <svg width="300px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="10" y="50" font-size="30">My SVG</text>
  </svg>
```