# DomSanitizer change attributes to lower case on bypassSecurityTrustHtml

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-dom-sanitizer

I have a pipe that uses DomSanitizer to bypass HTML. It's bypassing it. But, it converts all attributes inside the element to lower case. The pipe looks like this:

```js
    @Pipe({
        name: 'innerHTML'
    })
    export class InnerHTMLPipe implements PipeTransform {

        constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

        transform(value: any, args?: any): SafeHtml {
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value ? value : '');
        }
    }
```

The component that generates the string looks like this:

```html
    <div [innerHTML]="getProgress(data) | innerHTML"></div>
```

```js
    return `<span
        matTooltipPosition="above"
        matTooltip="blablabla">hello</span>`;
```

But the output ends up like this:

```html
    <div>
        <span mattooltipposition="above" mattooltip="blablabla">hello</span>
    </div>
```

How do I prevent DomSanitizer from changing the attributes and keep the attributes intact?

Comment: I think angular will not allow to intialize mattooltipposition directive using domsanitizer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it doesn't do that, all `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` does is store your string in a class property:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bbeac0727b8f267a47aba1ff1bcfc8cc5ca15b61/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L204

Secondly, you cannot get Angular directives to work simply by adding them to DOM manually.

Thirdly, html is case-insensitive so it wouldn't matter in theory:
[Is HTML case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351857/is-html-case-sensitive)