# How to keep everything when inserting custom HTML as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

Suppose the following example:

```
let html = `<Parent customAttr={ value }>
    <Child className="container" />
</Parent>`;

let div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = html;
// or
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

console.log(div);
```

When inserting the `html` variable as `innerHTML` of the `div`, first letters of `<Parent>` and `<Child>` elements become lowercased, camelCase of the attributes are lost and `{ value }` becomes wrapped into double quotes.

Is it possible and how to keep everything without these changes when inserting as `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [mdn web docs :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#usage_notes)

> What exactly happens when you set value of innerHTML? Doing so causes
> the user agent to follow these steps:
>
> The specified value is parsed as HTML or XML (based on the document
> type), resulting in a DocumentFragment object representing the new set
> of DOM nodes for the new elements. If the element whose contents are
> being replaced is a  element, then the  element's
> content attribute is replaced with the new DocumentFragment created in
> step 1. For all other elements, the element's contents are replaced
> with the nodes in the new DocumentFragment.

so you can't do what you want with innerHtml

Comment: Additionally: Since [parsing HTML is case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351857/13561410), using `innerHTML` will cause you to lose your case-sensitive information.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it's possible at least to avoid adding the closing tag for `<Child />` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add content to the element.

```
div.innerHTML += html
```

Comment: It's the same as `div.innerHTML = html`

Comment: @stkuser **div.innerHTML = html** updates content of div while **div.innerHTML += html** adds content to div.

Comment: I mean the result in my case is the same - it doesn't (and can't as mentioned above) resolve the issue